# Publishing App Not Triggering OnSteamReceived Event

Tags: android, opentok

I have two Android devices running separate TokBox apps which are trying to communicate with each other through video chat. I am having a problem in getting the OnStreamReceived event from one of my application which is publishing the video chat. But the application that subscribes the video triggers the event. I need the event to be triggered on the publishing side. Can anybody let me know the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokbox QA staff here.

Not sure what you mean with "separate Tokbox apps", but, if you use the same API Key for both ends, and you connect to the same session, the *OnStreamReceived* event would be received by the subscribers, not the publisher. This event will be triggered when another client **publishes** a stream, which means that the subscriber will not trigger the event. You can find further information here:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/android/#detect_streams

Comment: Thanks I resolved it by adding code from the sample code for basicvideo. Now I am able to view the videos.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

As Fran mentioned, the `onStreamReceived` will only fire when another client in the session publishes. If you want to know when the publisher has started to publish from the publisher's perspective, please use this method:

`public void onStreamCreated(PublisherKit publisherKit, Stream stream) {
       // publishing - do something
    }`

Answer (score 0):

About half the time the Publisher.StreamCreated event doesn't fire. The breakpoint simply isn't hit and the subscribers are therefore not notified since the publisher isn't sending anything. It's really hit or miss and frustrating.